# Postgresql SKU Generator

Tags: postgresql

i'm looking for SKU generator function to generate SKU based on product name, combination of letter and 5 digit unique number in Postgresql.

For example :

```
generate_sku('GREENFIELDS FULL CREAM MILK')
```

will return only 3 first word and random number :

```
GRE-FUL-CRE-987652
```

Any idea ?

Comment: The first part is trivial, for the number use a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested create a sequence. Since you have a specific value range restrict the range of the sequence. Then create a function which take a single parameter, the name, and returns the SKU. See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=de6adbfc3faefd54b189f42abef9ae04).

```
create sequence sku_seq
       as         integer
       increment  1
       start with 10000
       minvalue   10000
       maxvalue   99999
       no cycle; 
       
 
create or replace 
function item_sku(item_name_in text)
  returns  text 
  language sql 
  immutable strict
as $$
with parm (snam) as 
     ( select string_to_array(item_name_in, ' '))
select sku || to_char(nextval('sku_seq'),'FM99999')
  from ( select case 
                when array_length(snam,1)  > 2  
                     then substr(snam[1],1,3) ||'_' ||
                          substr(snam[2],1,3) ||'_' ||
                          substr(snam[3],1,3) ||'_' 
                when array_length(snam,1)  = 2 
                     then substr(snam[1],1,3) ||'_' ||
                          substr(snam[2],1,3) ||'_' 
                else substr(snam[1],1,3) || '_'
                end sku
         from parm
       ) s ;
$$;
```